# Multiple OR conditions within AND condition in SQL

Tags: sql

Basic question. In SQL, if I want to make a query where a column (e.g Merchant) must meet either one of the condition, would the following statement work? Or is there a better way of doing it. Thanks!

```
select Member from Sales
where Transaction = 'Card'
and Time_Period between '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-01'
and (Merchant like '%pizza'
or Merchant like '%cafe%'
or Merchant like 'mcdonald'
or Merchant like 'ubereats')
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  It should work although there are simpler ways to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select Member from Sales 
where 
   Transaction = 'Card' 
   and Time_Period between '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-01' 
   and Merchant in ('pizza','cafe','mcdonald','ubereats')
```

this should work in most SQL dialects
You don't need to use LIKE for exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for direct match so instead of like you can use "=" (Merchant='pizza'). And instead of using four comparison with or you can use `IN` as below:

```
select Member from Sales
where Transaction = 'Card'
and Time_Period between '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-01'
and Merchant in ('pizza','cafe','mcdonald','ubereats')
```

You can't use `Merchant in ('%pizza%','%cafe%')`

but if you really want to avoid multiple or below trick will work (but it will be much slower in performance). But, as  @Antonín Lejsek mentioned join can provide duplicate rows if any row satisfy more than one like condition. So you need to use distinct which will further slowdown the query.

```
 select distinct Member from Sales
 join (select '%pizza%' colPattern union all select '%cafe%' union all select '%mcdonald%' union all select '%ubereats%')t
    where Transaction = 'Card'
    and Time_Period between '2021-01-01' and '2021-02-01'
    and Merchant like colPattern
```

Comment: thanks! may I ask if the query is not using direct matches are there other possible ways for doing it? For example '%pizza' and '%cafe%'?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: i use SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I m afraid that with like operator you need to use multiple or as you wrote in your question.

Comment: The join can produce duplicate rows in the result.

Comment: Thanks @AntonínLejsek for the correction.